# Airflow tasks get stuck at “Scheduled” status and never gets running during backfill

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Trying to do some backfills, and all the dag runs start up fine, but for some reason they can't get by a specific task, instead they get stuck in a "Scheduled" state. Not sure what "Scheduled" means and why they don't move to "Running". It works fine in the daily run, but the backfill gets stuck for some reason.

This is super annoying since it means I have to start all the tasks for the backfill manually, which works.

Any idea why a task might be stuck in a "Scheduled" state?

Comment: Which executor are you using?

Comment: I wonder if this is actually a duplicate of the other question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884879/how-do-i-queue-up-backfills-in-airflow. I think it might be the same problem causing both, but not sure so keeping them for now.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks stuck in a “queued” state usually mean one of two things, no queue to execute on or no pool to execute in.

Which executor are you using? Local, sequential, celery?

Comment: Google cloud composer is using the celery executor. From what I can tell none of the above should have happened.